# Using Wordpress wp_handle_upload function to upload images to custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to use the `wp_handle_upload` function in Wordpress to process an image upload by a user but store it in a custom table.

There is plenty of articles around about using the function, but all the images are stored in the `posts` table and uploads folder.

Or would I be better off trying to clone the functions and point them towards my custom table to store the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be going through a lot of hassle trying to manipulate the wp_handle_upload function.

However, take a look at this article: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67763/how-to-change-upload-directory-in-wp-handle-upload

I would also suggest to find some alternative method or plugin to fulfill your desire.